# CKfinder BrowseServer functionality on https

Tags: https, ckfinder

I use the standard BrowseServer function to popup a CKfinder (version 2.4.2). This works perfect using http, but when i use https on the same page the popup is showing a blank screen.

Any tips?

```
function BrowseServer ()
{
    var finder = new CKFinder();
    finder.basePath = '../ckfinder/';
    finder.selectActionFunction = SetFileField;
    finder.popup();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has to do with https. You can try uncomment the lines with "//" in order to dump SERVER errors then be sure of what is happening.

```
/*
 Uncomment lines below to enable PHP error reporting and displaying PHP errors.
 Do not do this on a production server. Might be helpful when debugging why CKFinder does not work as expected.
*/
 // error_reporting(E_ALL);
 // ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```